# GAE compatible java portal

Tags: google-app-engine, portal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Portlet container like pluto or jetspeed on google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597854/portlet-container-like-pluto-or-jetspeed-on-google-app-engine)

Is there any java based portal which is compatible with  Google App Engine? Portal mean it should smiler to iGogle and Apache Jetspeed.

I have check that Apache Jetspeed but it has several bugs.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this may useful to you. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597854/portlet-container-like-pluto-or-jetspeed-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Shindig](http://shindig.apache.org/) is a open source implementation of an OpenSocial container. This is a reference implementation for the same API that are used in the iGoogle gadget container.

I think it runs on a in-mem SQL database (derby, sqlite?) but maybe could be configured to use Google Cloud SQL and maybe could run on AppEngine. I guess it may take a lot of tinkering to get it to run on AppEngine.